# Crystal report not opening in client machine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm not able to open crystal reports on client machine. Crystal report runtime is installed and .Net framework as well.

Error code below
                See the end of this message for details on invoking 
                just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
            ************** Exception Text **************
            System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for &#39;CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument&#39; threw an exception. ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
            at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
            at HW_Management.Report..ctor()
            at HW_Management.ContainerMDI.reportToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
            at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


            ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
            mscorlib
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            HW Management
            Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft/HardwareManagementSystem/HW%20Management.exe
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Windows.Forms
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Drawing
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Configuration
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Core
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Xml
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Data
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Transactions
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.EnterpriseServices
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            System.Numerics
            Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
            Win32 Version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
            Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
            Win32 Version: 13.0.12.1494
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
            ----------------------------------------
            CrystalDecisions.Shared
            Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
            Win32 Version: 13.0.12.1494
            CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Shared/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
            ----------------------------------------

            ************** JIT Debugging **************
            To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
            application or computer (machine.config) must have the
            jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
            The application must also be compiled with debugging
            enabled.

            For example:

            &lt;configuration&gt;
            &lt;system.windows.forms jitDebugging=&quot;true&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;/configuration&gt;

            When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
            will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
            rather than be handled by this dialog box.</pre>
```

Comment: your Crystal report file is not able to find

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar ; The application working fine on machine, in client machine only the issue is coming. I placed the file on the proper file path and I verified it in the code as well. Any other suggestion Plz

Comment: @MHakvoort I verified the Assembly folder and the file is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to .Net Framework upgrade.
Check aspnet_client  and make sure you have proper proper folder that corresponds to the lastest .net version